# Need help to fix 'EOF' docker-compose.yml

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker

I'm using `.yml` template to launch WordPress with docker container but the template fail launching docker-compose. I also want to connect to an RDS mysql instance on AWS.

```
sudo su
sudo apt update -y
touch docker-compose.yml
cat << EOF > docker-compose.yml
version: '3.7'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "endpoint:3306"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wpuser
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: database0000
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpressdb
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}: /var/lib/mysql  
EOF
sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?  Does the `docker-compose.yml` file contain the content you expect, after the shell handles it?  (Can you create a fixed `docker-compose.yml` file without generating it in this script?)  Is the extra space after `${HOME}: ` a problem?

Comment: I think you should use quotes around the delimiter, i.e. `cat <<"EOF" > docker-compose.yml`. This will [escape](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/heredoc-herestring#6-escape-special-characters-in-here-document) the `${HOME}` in the file, which is probably what you want. another issue might be the space after the colon in the first volume item.